# Couldn't build my application with realm. throws error saying realm's constructor is not found in iOS and can't configure realm in android

Tags: realm, react-native, react-native-ios

Recently I changed my system and when I try to build my application in my new MacBook it doesn't builds with realm. 
    Two errors in android.
    1) A problem occurred configuring project ':realm'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified.
>       2) A problem occurred evaluating project ':realm'.
>   Extension not initialized yet, couldn't access compileSdkVersion.
>           and in iOS it says it couldn't find the realm constructor.

I've already checked the compilesdk versions on the main gradle file and in the realm module's gradle file. they look fine.

```
{
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$projectDir/../../react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

task forwardDebugPort(type: Exec) {
    def adb = android.getAdbExe()?.toString() ?: 'false'
    commandLine adb, 'forward', 'tcp:8083', 'tcp:8083'
    ignoreExitValue true
    doLast {
        if (execResult.getExitValue() != 0) {
            logger.error(
                '===========================================================================\n' +
                'WARNING: Failed to automatically forward port 8083.\n' +
                'In order to use Realm in Chrome debugging mode, port 8083 must be forwarded\n' +
                'from localhost to the device or emulator being used to run the application.\n' +
                'You may need to add the appropriate flags to the command that failed:\n' +
                '    adb forward tcp:8083 tcp:8083\n' +
                '===========================================================================\n'
            )
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.hasProperty("compileSdkVersion") ? rootProject.compileSdkVersion : 28
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.hasProperty("buildToolsVersion") ? rootProject.buildToolsVersion : "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.hasProperty("minSdkVersion") ? rootProject.minSdkVersion : 16
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.hasProperty("targetSdkVersion") ? rootProject.targetSdkVersion : 28
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn forwardDebugPort
    }
}

def dependencyType = "implementation"
try {
    project.getConfigurations().getByName("implementation")
} catch (UnknownConfigurationException e) {
    dependencyType = "compile" // Pre 3.0 Android Gradle Plugin
}

project.dependencies {
    add(dependencyType, fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']))
    add(dependencyType, 'org.nanohttpd:nanohttpd:2.2.0')
    add(dependencyType, 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+')
}
}
```